# How to print struct verbosely, with hiding some fields?

Tags: go, logging

I need to print all form requests to log, for later debugging. I need to have something like this, where `formInput` are different kind of structs. (All defined in my code.)

```
type SomeFormInput {
    Name string
    Age int
}

func handleForm(formInput interface{}) {
    ...
    logger.Logf("%+v", formInput);
}
```

However, some of the forms contain "secret" data that needs to be sanitized before logging - specifically, passwords.

What is the best and easiest way to do this, without losing the generality of `handleForm`?

I still need it to accept `interface{}`.

I can use tags if needed.

```
type SomeFormInput struct {
    Name string
    Password string `hide:"true"` // something like this
}
```

Comment: one way would consist of providing the password to the logger then erase it from each input received (once stringified, just run strings.Replace). Another way is to declare a marshaller, that can handle some secific tags as you demonstrated in your post

Comment: `one way would consist of providing the password to the logger then erase it from each input received (once stringified, just run strings.Replace).` - good idea, you can write it as a normal answer and I will accept

Comment: custom marshaler is just too complex :P

Comment: yes, though, it is a possible solution.

Comment: What I realized - I can also use `JSON` marshaler (so JSON.marshal instead of verbose log) and tag `json:"-"`. It's a bit dumb, but good enough.

Comment: @KarelBílek It's not dumb, it often offers better output than `"%+v"` of the `fmt` package. And it's a ready solution.

Comment: yes, though, this could (potentially) conflict. Maybe later you will need to transmit that password, anyways, and you will be stuck

Comment: Good point, but this is not an issue now

Comment: "custom marshaler is just too complex :P" -- What? I can't tell if this is sarcastic, or serious.

Comment: @Flimzy you need to use `reflect` and go through all the fields? And check the tags? Using reflect is almost always complex? Or maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: Why would you use reflect in a custom marshaler?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. I thought he meant some custom re-implementation of verbose printing that is still general, but also looking at the tags. He/you meant an actual JSON marshaler. Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no completely general solution to this.  There are only specific solutions with different trade-offs.

1. Perhaps the *most* general solution would be to write a function that inspects each form type with reflection, and omits any sensitive fields in the output.

   ```
   logger.Logf("%s", stripPassword(formInput));
   ```

   This has the side effect of no longer using the `%+v` verb, which often won't matter, but if your type implements the [fmt.Formatter](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Formatter) interface, it will change behavior. But then again, your goal is to change behavior, so...

Which leads to a second option:

2. You could implement a custom `Format()` method on your type, to cause `%+v` (or `%v` or `%s`) to output whatever you desire (omitting private fields).
3. Along the same lines, but easier, if you're logging (or willing to log) JSON output, just impliment your own `json.Marshaler` for each type. Example:

   ```golang
   func (i *SomeFormInput) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
       intermediate := struct{
           *SomeFormInput
           Password    struct{} `json:"-"` // Occlude Password field in the embedded struct
           MarshalJSON struct{} `json:"-"` // Occlude MarshalJSON method on embedded struct, to avoid infinite loop
       }{
           SomeFormInput: i,
       }
       return json.Marshal(intermediate)
   }
   ```
4. A similar option is to use the `json:"-"` tag for fields that should not be output. Example:

   ```golang
   type SomeFormInput struct {
       Name     string
       Password string `json:"-"`
   }
   ```
5. And as a final option, you could filter the log output, prior to sending it to the logger. If you're using JSON, you could parse the data using the tokenizing [json.Decoder](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder), to omit only the keys you want.  For arbitrary text, perhaps a regular expression could be used.

For most applications I work on, where I practically always use JSON logging, I would probably prefer option #4, followed by #5.